# Badge for somehow hitting 666

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badges, reputation

Given that the scores seem to be given in order's of 5's and 10's with the odd 2's, sitting on 666 seems likely rare.  A badge for this would be interesting.

[image]

Comment: Considering you start with either 1 or 101 reputation, 666 is not any more difficult than obtaining 665 would be.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The point of badges is to reward behavior we want to encourage.  Giving badges for getting a precise rep display for a bit doesn't really reward anything, it just gives people with 667 rep a reason to downvote a random post.

Just take a screenshot of your milestones.

[image]

Comment: You're right.  I had forgotten that we started at 101.

Comment: ... and that you can force a -1 on your own score by downvoting an answer.

Comment: I also did not know that you affect your own with downvotes(really?).  I did venture too far with this question at my stage.  Apologies.

Comment: Now, I'm fairly new- but aren't down-votes for 'bad' questions, not questions that get negative answers?  It's important to know what badges are for.  My question, and its answers, emphasized that with context.  Should I refer to these results in a follow-up question?  Not one downvote to this point actually left a comment on why my question was 'bad'.

Comment: Don't take it personally, on the meta sites upvotes and downvotes just indicate agreement or disagreement, not post quality.

Comment: Acknowledged, and I see why there's differentiation.  Painful, though.

Comment: Damn... I missed my chance to screen-grab my 66,666 rep :(   To the Photoshop!